# RubyMotion add Action to Keyboard Button Event

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Wondering how I would add an action to a keyboard event in iOS using RubyMotion.

i.e. If I had a button I could do:

`@button.addTarget(self, action: "performAction:",  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)`

But what about when the user presses a Keyboard button?

Specifically. I'm using a `UISearchBar` and once the user types in their query I'd like them to be able to use the `Search` button to call a function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that works for my case.

First I create the `UISearchBar` and in this case I add it to my `UINavigationBar`

```
search = UISearchBar.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 0))
search.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal
search.delegate = self
navigationItem.titleView = search
```

Then I create a function to override `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`

```
def searchBarSearchButtonClicked(search)
    puts "search button clicked"
    search.text = nil
    search.resignFirstResponder
end
```